# How can I tell which of these video devices is a webcam?

Tags: camera, devices

```
$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Mai  4 00:17 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Mai  4 00:17 /dev/video0
```

This is a laptop so I guess one is the built in camera, and one is the screen.  But how can I check which?  Is there a way to get more information about one of them?

Comment: The best but most stupid way is to use a video chat app like Discord and put on your camera. If one camera doen't work, use the other one. My sister and I use this method to test cam and mic

Comment: OK but when I open say zoom, it only lists cameras, so I guess my question might be... How does zoom know?

Comment: I really don't know how zoom knows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [do this with `v4l2-ctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/v4l2-ctl.1.html) in a terminal:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Install the utility (if it’s not already installed)

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install v4l2-ctl
   ```
3. Run the utility:

   ```
   v4l2-ctl --list-devices
   ```

   You will see output like this:

   ```
   Integrated Camera (usb-0000:00:3b.0-1.2):
       /dev/video0
   ```

One of the video devices you see in `/dev/video*` is a virtual device.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the install command; shouldn't it be `sudo apt install v4l-utils` ?

Comment: That does not always work, in my laptop I get 
`HP TrueVision HD: HP TrueVision (usb-0000:00:14.0-5):`
        `/dev/video0`
        `/dev/video1`, but I have only one camera.

Comment: @Archisman, I also have an HP machine, and `v4l2-ctl` also lists two devices (`/dev/video0`, `/dev/video1`). I wonder if one of these is the IR camera?

Comment: @PJSingh I don't think I have an IR camera.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package called `usbutils` which can be an invaluable tool:

```
sudo apt install usbutils
```

Then you can query any USB device and get a lot of information:

```
$ sudo lsusb -v | grep -i webcam -a14

Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1bcf:2b8c Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1bcf Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
  idProduct          0x2b8c 
  bcdDevice           47.14
  iManufacturer           1 SunplusIT Inc
  iProduct                2 Integrated_Webcam_HD
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          767
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               4 Integrated Webcam
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 Integrated Webcam
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength          109
        dwClockFrequency       48.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
```

Comment: I didn't expect `-a` (`--text`) receiving arguments. It seems to work like `-C`, they are equivalents?

Comment: @PabloBianchi You can use `-a#` for number of lines before and after `grep` match. You can use `-A#` for number of lines after `grep` match. I haven't used `-C` in `grep` before. What do  you use it for?

Comment: [`-C` (`--context`) is for context](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/grep.1.html#options). Seems exactly the same as `-a#`, which is undocumented, AFAIK. Notice that `-a` could _output binary  garbage_